# stackoverflow exception in webgrease VS2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I recently upgraded my visual studio from 2012 to 2015 every thing was working perfectly fine on VS 2012 but i am getting 
**"An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in WebGrease.dll"** when i run my application/code

[image]

below is details about version

**package id="WebGrease" version="1.1.0" targetFramework="net40"**

**Update: the fix i found**

There seems to be compatibility issue of webgrease(1.1.0) with vs2015 updrading it to WebGrease 1.6.0 solved the problem

Comment: From anecdotal experience, I seem to remember getting this problem and finding it to be a bug. Have you tried updating to a more recent version.

Comment: trying apply update 2

Comment: Not of Visual Studio, of WebGrease itself. Version 1.1.0 dates from 2012.

Comment: does somebody cares why downvotes?

Answer (score 0):

I recently ran into this, but for a very specific use case. I am using Syncfusion products in a project for a client.

My dev machine has(had) Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate and Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise installed, side by side. My WebGrease package was fully updated to 1.6.0.

When I updated to the latest version of Syncfusion, I started receiving the WebGrease StackOverflowException shown above, but only when I was in VS 2015. 2013 did not give me the same error.

I also did not get the error unless I added a specific Syncfusion JS file to my bundles. Everything ran as expected until I added that one bundle.

I even went through the trouble of removing the built-in bundling support of the project, by removing Antlr, WebGrease, System.Web.Optimization, etc. Doing that fixed my error, but it was not the solution I was looking for.

After some back & forth with Syncfusion support, they stated that they were able run the project on their machines that were using Visual Studio 2015. They stated that the problem must be on my machine.

I keep a very clean dev machine, only installing software that I absolutely need and nothing else. I was certain that the problem wasn't on my end and was in denial about the whole thing.

I tried to repair Visual Studio 2015 as well as uninstall/reinstall Visual Studio 2015. Neither worked.

Yesterday, I bit the bullet and wiped my machine and reinstalled everything. Now the project runs without error.

It's not the fix anyone wants to hear, but it is what ultimately solved my problem.

Cliff's Notes: I had the same problem. The fix ended up being wiping my machine and starting from scratch.